# Interoperating web components from NPM modules with Svelte

Tags: javascript, npm, svelte, web-component

I am building a basic Single Page App (SPA) using Svelte. I have been able to achieve basic layout and styling happily, and an asynchronous web request when you click a button.

Now, my goal is to use a [custom library's exported Web Component based on lit.js](https://github.com/source-data/render-rev/tree/main) to render the resulting data; however, I don't understand Web Components nor Svelte well enough to understand why I am getting the errors I am.

I would expect, based on the documentation of both projects, to be able to do something like this:

```
<script>
  import 'render-rev';
  let renderRevElement;

  async function loadData() { // called on button click, so dom is loaded
    renderRevElement.configure({
      doi: '10.1101/2020.07.20.212886',
      display: {
        publisherName: name => name.toUpperCase(),
      }
    });    
  }
</script>

<main>

  ...

    <render-rev bind:this="{renderRevElement}" doi="10.1101/2020.07.20.212886"></render-rev>
</main>
```

But the `renderRevElement` object only has one legal key: `__svelte_meta`, and no `configure` method. I suppose this means I have failed to correctly express that the `<render-rev...` component is coming from the imported module. How do I wire these up?

I have also tried `import 'render-rev/render-rev.js'`, calling `configure` at top level of script, and a few other things etc... what am I missing about how NPM modules are supposed to be consumed by Svelte components?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I discovered that the issue was my import statement was incorrect. The package in question is imported using an NPM namespace, which is undocumented. It worked when I did this: `import '@source-data/render-rev/render-rev.js'`.